# Directory bookmarks for open/save files in Matlab

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, directory, matlab

I have Matlab 7.11.0 (R2010b) under my Ubuntu 10.10.

Every time I need to save a new file edited in its editor, Matlab starts from my $home address, so I have to manually go directory by directory before getting to my destination.

I wonder if there is some way either by or outside Matlab that can made it smart to use the bookmarks in Nautilus, or store some history for quick accessing previous directories?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Matlab version there is a drop-down list called "Current Directory:" in the "Matlab Toolbar". It saves recent directories.

Also, in the editor, you can type `cd` and press the up button to get the relevant history.